# Match words then match potentially parenthetical string, then match potential square braced string

Tags: php, regex

I have a script where I need to get three parts out of a text string, and return them in an array. After a couple of trying and failing I couldn't get it to work.

The text strings can look like this:

```
Some place
Some place (often text in parenthesis)
Some place (often text in parenthesis) [even text in brackets sometimes]
```

I need to split these strings into three:

```
{Some place} ({often text in parenthesis}) [{even text i brackets sometimes}]
```

Which should return:

```
1: Some place
2: often text in parenthesis
3: even text in brackets sometimes
```

I know this should be an easy task, but I couldn't solve the correct regular expression. This is to be used in PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the parenthesis and brackets always come in the same order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$result = preg_match('/
  ^ ([^(]+?)
  (\s* \( ([^)]++) \))?
  (\s* \[ ([^\]]++) \])?
  \s*
  $/x', $mystring, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Note that in this example, you will probably be most interested in $matches[1], $matches[3], and $matches[5].

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem into three regular expressions. After the first one, where you get every character before the first parenthesis, save your position - the same as the length of the string you just extracted.

Then in step two, do the same, but grab everything up to the closing parenthesis. (Nested parentheses make this a little more complicated but not too much.)  Again, save a pointer to the end of the second string.

Getting the third string is then trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it as three regular expressions, starting with both parenthesis and brackets, and falling back to less items if that fails.

```
^(.*?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s+\[(.*?)\]\s+$
```

if it fails then try:

```
^(.*?)\s+\((.*?)\)\s+$
```

if that also fails try:

```
^\s+(.*?)\s+$
```

I'm sure they can be combined into one regular expression, but I wouldn't try.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
([^(]++)(?: \(([^)]++)\))?(?: \[([^\]]++)\])?
```